# Engagement (Nitchayathartham) after death of grandmother

Tags: belief, death, superstitions

I have a question about how Hindus (especially Tamil) deal with the engagement after the death of a family member.

If an engagement was planned for in 6 month but tragically the grandmother (father's side) passes away.

Does the engagement have to be cancelled and postponed for an year?

I'm searching for answers related to the tradition.